# EmguCV in C# QueryFrame returns the previous queried frame and using dispose adds delay in my application

Tags: c#

I am using **EmguCV** and am querying frames at some intervals from a Capture to be saved in a folder. The problem is when I call the `Capture.QueryFrame()` or `Capture.QuerySmallFrame()` it is delayed by a frame. I find the same problem here in stackoverflow and the answer is to use `Capture.Dispose`. I'm using `Capture.Dispose` and the above problem is solved but another problem arises. Using `Capture.Dispose` in my application make it work slower.

To make this more clear: My app works on an ATM. It takes a photo when the user enters pin or removes his card and money. When I use `Capture.Dispose`, the user has to wait longer.

Answer (score 1):

I simply solved the problem by calling Capture.QueryFrame() or Capture.QuerySmallFrame() twice.